# What does "that" mean in "is in the richest state that it has ever been in"?

Tags: pronouns

> Today humanity is in the richest state that it has ever been in.

Do you consider **that** correct here? Can it be substituted with **than**?

I think **that** would be wrong, but logically it fits in here. I can't spot an entry in a dictionary which conveys the meaning which **that** conveys in my sentence.

Comment: This should probably be retagged, since "that" isn't being used as a pronoun here.

Comment: Potentially helpful for you in the future -- the Google search `define:that` summarizes a bunch of info from dictionaries, and includes the relevant definition in under the fourth form (conjunction): "introducing a subordinate clause expressing a statement or hypothesis".  I use that search operator all the time.

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot switch 'that' to 'than' in this example. We use 'than' in comparisons with a *comparative adjective*, such as *richer*:

> Today, humanity is in **a richer** state **than** it has ever been in.

Your example uses the *superlative*, 'richest', so there is no comparison required - the superlative is greater than all others.

We use 'that' to introduce a defining clause - one that adds further, essential information - although it can be omitted and the sentence is still grammatically correct.

> - Today, humanity is in the richest state that it has ever been in.
> - Today, humanity is in the richest state it has ever been in.

Comment: Isn't 'that' a conjunction here, not a determiner?

Comment: _That_ is absolutely not a determiner here. It is a subordinator (more specifically a complementiser), the historical term for which would indeed be a [subordinating conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Subordinating_conjunctions). It initiates a relative clause and could also be replaced by a relative pronoun (_which_), with optional prepositional fronting (“richest state it has ever been in” → “richest state in which it has ever been”).

Comment: @Astralbee The criterion of a "clause standing on its own" is generally used to distinguish a "clause" from a "phrase". It's not referring to context. A clause only needs a subject and a verb that agrees with it. "It has ever been in" is [absolutely a clause](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/that#Conjunction). The only reason it seems like it doesn't stand alone is because of the adverb "ever". But modifiers to either the subject or verb *never* preclude a sentence structure from being a clause.

Comment: @Astralbee further, it cannot be a determiner because a determiner *by definition* is either an adjective or pronoun. In the example, it neither modifies "state" nor "it", so it's not an adjective. It is also not acting as a subject or object in any phrase or clause, so it's not a pronoun. It is a conjunction joining an independent and dependent clause.

Answer (score 9):

> Today humanity is in the richest state that it has ever been in.

That could be rewritten to illuminate the role **that** plays:

> Today humanity is in the richest state in which it has ever been.

**that it has ever been in** is a clause modifying the noun-phrase **the richest state** which is the object of preposition **in**.

**that** serves two roles there: it functions as the clause subordinator and serves as the proxy for **state** in the clause.